# blog excerpt in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've purchased a theme and the blog excerpt works fine on their demo site, but not on my website's blog overview page.
this is the code I found, but this is the wordpress post-template.php
The theme does not have any blog settings which leads me to think it's a wordpress issues?

Hopre someone can help,

Many thanks!

P.S. Php newbie so please explain how I can fix this.

```
function get_the_excerpt( $deprecated = '' ) {
    if ( !empty( $deprecated ) )
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '2.3' );

    $post = get_post();
    if ( empty( $post ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        return __( 'There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.' );
    }

    /**
     * Filter the retrieved post excerpt.
     *
     * @since 1.2.0
     *
     * @param string $post_excerpt The post excerpt.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );
}


/**
 * Whether post has excerpt.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 * @param int|WP_Post $id Optional. Post ID or post object.
 * @return bool
 */
function has_excerpt( $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    return ( !empty( $post->post_excerpt ) );
}

/**
 * Display the classes for the post div.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param string|array $class One or more classes to add to the class list.
 * @param int|WP_Post $post_id Optional. Post ID or post object.
 */
function post_class( $class = '', $post_id = null ) {
    // Separates classes with a single space, collates classes for post DIV
    echo 'class="' . join( ' ', get_post_class( $class, $post_id ) ) . '"';
}
```

Comment: Have you added excerpts to your posts?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply, I didn't realise I have to do that, I know it generally takes the excerpt from the body of the post and its generated in the overview. Am i wrong in thinking that?

Comment: According to the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt - there's an 'Excerpt' box on the post edit page, and you need to explicitly put an excerpt in that for it to be picked up.

Comment: Hi Andrew I just read that seconds ago. It seems there are 3 different types. I need the automatic one that is generated as a summary on the blog overview page. Thanks.

Comment: OK; then it's time to do some debugging. Try manually adding an excerpt to a post, and see if that comes back OK. If it does, then the auto-generated excerpt is broken. My WAG is that the `$post->post_excerpt` check is looking for a manually added excerpt only, but I'm somewhat rusty on WordPress's internal gubbins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `the_excerpt()` return the text in the excerpt field. Though you can use a filter to change what it returns:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt' );
```

It will trigger this function when `the_excerpt()` will be called:

```
function my_custom_excerpt($excerpt) {
    if(empty($excerpt)) {
        return get_custom_excerpt();
    } else {
        return $excerpt;
    }
}
```

That way a custom excerpt will be used if the excerpt field is empty. Here is the code for `get_custom_excerpt` (it will do a "smart" ceasure):

```
function print_excerpt($length)
{ 
    global $post;
    $text = $post->post_excerpt;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
            $text = get_the_content('');
            $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
            $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
    }
    $text = strip_shortcodes($text);
    $text = strip_tags($text, '<a>'); // change this to the tags you want to keep

    if (preg_match('/^.{1,'.$length.'}\b/s', $text, $match))
        $text = $match[0];
    $excerpt = reverse_strrchr($text, array('.','!'), 1, 100);
    if($excerpt) {
            echo apply_filters('the_excerpt',$excerpt);
    } else {
            echo apply_filters('the_excerpt',$text.'...');
    }
}
function reverse_strrchr($haystack, $needle, $trail, $offset=0)
{
    return strrposa($haystack, $needle, $offset) ? substr($haystack, 0, strrposa($haystack, $needle, $offset) + $trail) : false;
}
// strrpos in Array mode
function strrposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0)
{
    if(!is_array($needles))
        $needles = array($needles);
    foreach($needles as $query) {
        if(strrpos($haystack, $query, $offset) !== false)
            return strrpos($haystack, $query, $offset);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi vard, thanks a lot for your answer. Would this work if I add it to my child theme functions.php or do I need to replace any of the existing code? Thanks!

Comment: Yes this all need to be add in your child _functions.php_ theme file

Comment: I've copied all and added it to the functions.php and it's not actually working. :(

Comment: In your post template file is the_excerpt called? Or the_content?

Comment: this is my post-template.php but it's the original wordpress one, not the theme one as the theme does not have one. http://pastebin.com/tFGwUruR

Comment: Well what you linked is not the template, it's the WP post function file. You should look in your theme for `index.php` - it's the template used for displaying the posts.

Comment: No I mean the index.php inside your theme folder - this is the root index file you pasted

Comment: Sorry vard, please see above I had just realised that as I posted it lol!

Comment: All right so it's a bit tricky - theme is using a shortcode to display the posts. There should be some template file somewhere in the theme folder that handle that, hard to know without having access to the theme files. I think they probably changed the excerpt function default behaviour. You may want to ask them directly - or tell us the theme name, maybe one of us already worked with.

Comment: I will ask them as well , but also would it help if I send over the theme via wetransfer? Thanks so much for you time!

Comment: You can send the theme files if you want, I will take a look at it.

Comment: I hope it's ok if i get back to you on this tomorrow, I must leave my pc now, hope you will have a little spare time on your hands tomorrow and I will also email the theme dev. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi vard please download the theme here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/d2nst1
I have also emailed the theme dev.

Comment: Hello Nicole, I just looked at it, could you change the line 77 of _blog-item-default.php_ (in the templates folder) `echo  '<p>'.do_shortcode(get_the_content('&nbsp;')).'</p>';` to `echo  '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>';` ? It should display the excerpt instead of the full content.